# Creating a file on disk partition gives error message

Tags: windows-7, privileges

My Windows 7 is on an SSD disk, and I have HDD disk from old Windows XP divided into several partitions. When I try to create a file on one of those partitions H:, it gives me an error:

> 0x80070522 A required privilege is not held by the client.

Creating files works fine if I go inside any folder. I'm using an administrator account, and I have tried setting an owner and changing privileges, but nothing works.

Comment: The same issue. Only elevated processes can create/modify files in the root of the drive. Seems that something wrong with ACLs