# Windows 7 can't write to root of non-system drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating file on disk partition gives 0x80070522](https://superuser.com/questions/454974/creating-file-on-disk-partition-gives-0x80070522)

I have my C: drive which is an SSD, and an F: drive which is a 500GB hard drive.

I cannot write to the root of the hard drive, unless elevated as an administrator. The error code is: 0x80070522: "A required privilege is not held by the client.".

I've tried taking ownership of the drive as well as granting "full control" permissions, to no avail.

It might be of interest that the drive *used* to be the root of a windows install, and has NOT been formatted since. Copying all the data to another location and re-formatting the drive is not really an option at the moment.

Is there any way I can force Windows to allow writes to the root of this NON-system drive?

By the way, please don't suggest disabling UAC.

Comment: What file system does it have on the F:?

Comment: If you look in Disk Management, what does it list as the roles/status for that partition (listed in brackets under "Status")?

Comment: NTFS. The reason I want to be able to write to the root is so that I can store my Photoshop scratch file there.

Comment: It just says "Healthy (Page File)" under the status thing.

Comment: How are you trying to "write to the root"?  In the permissions, have you ensured there's no Deny rules in place (they will overrule any Allow rules)?  Does it work without elevation if you turn off UAC?

Comment: There are no deny rules in place, and I am trying to write to the root by right clicking and hitting "new bitmap image". Or, by trying to get Photoshop to use F: as its scratch disk.

Comment: Have you run disk checks to ensure the drive/partition/file system is in a healthy state?

Comment: No, but the error is due to UAC, not a filesystem error. UAC is preventing me from writing to the root of a drive, because it thinks it's the system drive for some reason. Do you think it's actually worth doing a disk check?

Comment: Yes, and I also think it's worth moving your pagefile off that drive, as it may be the (system) file in the root that UAC is trying to protect.

Comment: Where would you suggest moving the page file? I need it (commonly paging despite having 8GB RAM - photo editing for you). It's not going on the SSD :P

Comment: I'm not suggesting you move it permanently, just move it for testing. PS if it was me, and I had the room, I'd be doing my best to get my page file ONTO my SSD since I like speed and I know that it's not going to prematurely kill my SSD (unlike what's said by a lot of misinformation out there on the Internet).

Comment: I removed my page file, and the problem isn't fixed. I really want to fix this issue. It *seems* like poor programming on Microsoft's part.